# Autosave option in Office 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office

Is there any auto save option in Office 2007 applications like we have in Google Docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's been a feature since at least office 2000:

http://www.technipages.com/word-2007-enabledisable-autosave.html